# OkHttp async call replaces thread name in log

Tags: java, java-8, okhttp

I use okhttp client to make async calls and log the request and response...

```
public void sendRequest(String requestJson) {    
    LOG.info("Sending payload: {}", requestJson);
    Request httpRequest = buildRequest(requestJson, url);
    okHttpClient.newCall(httpRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            LOG.info("Received response: {}", response.body().string());
            // Do things with response...
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, I have a problem with my logging. The request log shows up fine where pattern layout `%t` is replaced with the value I need i.e. a device Id in this case. However, because of the async call, that thread name is replaced with `OkHttp http://localhost:8080/...`. It's like the below;

```
[11:54:29:025] INFO  [Device_778445] TestDeviceClient - Sending payload:...
[11:54:30:011] INFO  [OkHttp http://localhost:8080/...] TestDeviceClient - Received response: ...
```

Is this possible to retain the %t/thread name value in async okhttp requests?

What I am looking for in short:

```
[11:54:29:025] INFO  [Device_778445] TestDeviceClient - Sending payload:...
[11:54:30:011] INFO  [Device_778445] TestDeviceClient - Received response: ...
```

**NOTE:**
I can work around this by getting the deviceId in a method argument and setting it back in onResponse method as the tread name, but I am not sure if this is preferable or if there is a better way...

Workaround like this;

```
public void sendRequest(String requestJson, String deviceId) {    
    LOG.info("Sending payload: {}", requestJson);
    Request httpRequest = buildRequest(requestJson, url);
    okHttpClient.newCall(httpRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Thread.currentThread.setName(deviceId);
            LOG.info("Received response: {}", response.body().string());
            // Do things with response...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the thread where `onResponse()` is called is not `Device_778445` but `OkHttp http://localhost:8080/...`. If you want a different behavior, use your own logger.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes I understand the thread name has changed. But not sure what you mean by my own logger. I am using my own logger, it is configured with the format I want. Or do you mean my own logger configured with okhttp?

Comment: If you're using your own logger then what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conceptual misunderstanding.
Using asynchronous processing means using some other thread(s) to do a job while the thread that is passing the task is not getting blocked.

So it's absolutely fine that the okhttp thread have its own name.
Changing it to something other is also conceptually wrong.

Your problem is that you are using a thread name as a identifier to detect user's actions. Thread name is not a place for that.
What you may do is to pass additional device id as a parameter, and to remove from the logger pattern thread name if it is not important for you.

```
LOG.info("{}: Received response: {}", deviceId, response.body().string());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see what you are saying. Do you think it will be better to add a custom name in the logging pattern and replace that with the device name using `MDC.put("custom name here", device Id here)`, so it stays constant across the application? And I can just leave the thread name as is.